# NHibernate - dirty ISession not updating

Tags: nhibernate

When the save button is clicked, the following code is run [PersistenceSession is a property returning an ISession instance]:

```
_storedWill = PersistenceSession.Load<StoredWill>(_storedWillId);
_storedWill.WillReference = txtWillReference.Text;
_storedWill.IntroducerReference = txtIntroducerReference.Text;
//A stack of other properties of the _storedWill object assigned
PersistenceSession.SaveOrUpdate(_storedWill);
```

A breakpoint set on the final line reveals that PersistenceSession.IsDirty() is true.

However, no update SQL is generated. Can anyone think why?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Flush` the session to have the updates sent to the database. `SaveOrUpdate` will not send anything to the database unless you are persisting a newly-created entity, whose ID values are database generated. Since you are just updating, all this does is ensures that the `_storedWill` entity is associated with the `ISession` returned by the `PersistenceSession` property.

Comment: Oh, it's you again, with your trombone! How are tricks? :)

Or you can create an ITransaction and commit it. I'm not sure of the pluses/minuses of each approach.

Comment: :) Fine thanks. Not sure if the ITransaction approach will try to use a distributed transaction, which of course may be problematic in certain environments due to possible firewall port requirements.